# Merge sort based on number of values in arrays

Tags: javascript, sorting, merge

I would like to understand how to use merge sort to sort arrays based on the number of values in each array.

```
let test = [
{
name: "a",
numbers: [1,2]
},{
name: "b",
numbers: [1,2,3]
},{
name: "c",
numbers: [5]
```

The 'a' has 2 numbers, the 'b' has 3 numbers and the 'c' has 1 number.
So it should be sorte as follows, from high to low: b, a, c.

Comment: Have you tried something? I mean, do you have a sample code that performs merge sort?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value

Answer (score 5):

Just use the array sort with a compare function.
The function should substract the lengths of the numbers property of objects.
More info: [Array.sort() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
test.sort((a, b) => b.numbers.length - a.numbers.length)
```

Comment: How about if it was like this:

let test = [
{
name: "abc",
numbers: [1,2]
},{
name: "def",
numbers: [1,2,3]
},{
name: "ghi",
numbers: [5]}

And it should be from high to low: def, abc, ghi...?

Comment: @EnTil `test.sort((a, b) => b.numbers.length - a.numbers.length).map(o => o.name)`

Comment: It does not work with arrays with other names than a, b and c...

Comment: @EnTil Please post an example of such array

Comment: Because this works `[ { name: "abc", numbers: [1,2] },{ name: "def", numbers: [1,2,3] },{ name: "ghi", numbers: [5]}].sort((a, b) => b.numbers.length - a.numbers.length).map(o => o.name)`, It gives `['def', 'abc', 'ghi']`

Comment: Please also explain *what* this is doing, for future questioners landing on this question.

Comment: @Roy updated. Though it's hard to explain more than giving a link to the docs. Does this look good enough? And second question, why is it better to use (lets call it) block code than inline code (3 backticks instead of 1)?

Comment: One backtick is mostly used for inline code elements, with three backticks before and after on newline, you can even specify the code language. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362